# How does this imply $x = z^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, fractions, partial-fractions

I read that given the equation:

$$
x + \frac{1}{x} = z^2 + \frac{1}{z^2}
$$

, we can imply that $x=z^2$.

But that $x=z^2$ is not obvious to me... I know we can match the variables on the left hand side to the right hand side, but how do we show that this holds in general?

Comment: Just solve it as a quadratic in $x$ and see what the solution is

Comment: Well, clearly we could have $x=\frac 1 {z^2}$ as well.

Comment: @GeorgeDewhirst, could you clarify how to solve it as a quadratic? thanks

Comment: yes just multiply through by $x$ to get your quadratic

Comment: Once you recognise it is a quadratic, the obvious fact that $z^2, \frac1{z^2}$ satisfy the equation is enough to conclude these are the only roots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you clear out the denominators:
\begin{align*}
    x + \frac{1}{x} &= z^2 + \frac{1}{z^2} 
\\\implies  \frac{x^2+1}{x} &= \frac{z^4+z^2}{z^2}
\\\implies  z^2x^2 + z^2 &= z^4 x + x 
\\\implies  z^2x^2 + z^2 - z^4 x - x &= 0 
\\\implies (z^2x-1)(x-z^2) &= 0
\end{align*}
So $x=z^2$ or $x = \frac{1}{z^2}$.